# DH key size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 2048 (inclusive)

Tags: java, jenkins, ssh, ant, solaris-10

I have a set-up in which I am executing a build from Jenkins on a Solaris Server connecting via `sshexec` task in `ANT`.

On trigerring the build, it is throwing below error:

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: DH key size must be
>   multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 2048 (inclusive). The
>   specific key size 2047 is not supported.

After some google search, I came to know that it might be fixed by updating to Java 8. I did that, however, still no success.

Can anyone please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: Please see if this helps - http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/customize_size_ephemeral.html

Comment: Thanks, Rao. Unfortunately, the shared article didn't help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you using key size more than a 2048

Comment: How to find it? This is the build script that I am executing via Jenkins: <sshexec host="my.host.com"   username="myuser"   password="mypass"   command="touch somefile"   trust="true" />

Comment: @NishantKansal Are there any updates on this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @NishantKansal do you have any updates on this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 10):

Our fix:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1)
```

we were using Jsch 0.1.54 directly to connect to an SFT server and saw:

> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: DH key size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 4096 (inclusive). The specific key size 2047 is not supported

possibly related

- [JDK-8164963: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException prime size issue after JDK upgrade with JSCH libraries](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8164963).
- [DHGEX failing with 2048-bit key under Java 8, but succeeding with 1024-bit key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869631/dhgex-failing-with-2048-bit-key-under-java-8-but-succeeding-with-1024-bit-key)

Comment: I maintained a standalone version of JSch and we can minor the effect of register a Bouncy castle security provider without add it into a global provider at here - https://github.com/gaoxingliang/JSch/

Comment: resolved, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JSch library (used by Jenkins or one of it's plugins) makes use of Java's JCE provider. It appears the JCE provider of your Java version can't handle the key length of 2047 bits.

You can swap your current JCE provider with a **BouncyCastle** provider.

While [@Brian Low](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43121592/2500832)'s workaround describes a dynamic registration of BouncyCastle as the cryptography package provider, I'd like to point out an alternative way where it's done by configuring your environment via static registration.

- Download BouncyCastle provider from [bouncycastle.org](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html)

Look for the "Signed JAR Files" section and select your provider. For example, **bcprov-jdk15to18**-165.jar, for any Java version between 5 and 8.

- In Jenkins go to Manage Jenkins - Global Tool Configurations - JDK to verify your JDK location (JAVA_HOME).
- Copy the JAR file to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext
- Locate and edit $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security

Here we insert the BouncyCastle provider at the first position (most prefered) and update the others' preference number.

Example:

```
#
# List of providers and their preference orders (see above):
#
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.2=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.6=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.7=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.8=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.9=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.10=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.11=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

At this point restart Jenkins.