# SFTP Connector DH Key Error

Tags: java, mule, sftp, jsch

I'm in the process of creating a simple Mule flow in Anypoint Studio - it polls a directory periodically, and when a file is placed in the directory it sends it to an SFTP server. However, when the application starts negotiating a secure connection with the server, it fails with this error:

> java.io.IOException: Error during login to username@host:
>   Session.connect: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: DH
>   key size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 8192
>   (inclusive). The specific key size 2047 is not supported

The stack trace references several files from the jsch library. The solutions in previous questions recommended upgrading to Java 8, using a different version of jsch, or editing the jsch jars themselves. My Mule server (version 3.9.0 EE) is already on Java 8, I've tried a few different versions of jsch, and editing the jars is not practical, since this application will be deployed to a few different environments.

I'm able to log in to the sftp server using the same credentials as the application via WinSCP. A coworker has tried modifying a working flow to use the same credentials to move the same file, and they get the same error. Here is the XML of my flow:

```
<flow name="ClCoFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="${file.from}"
            moveToDirectory="${file.backup}" responseTimeout="10000"
            doc:name="Get File to Transfer" />
        <logger
            message="#[flowVars.originalFilename] being moved to #[flowVars.moveToDirectory]"
            level="INFO" doc:name="File In" />
        <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            host="${sftp.host}" port="${sftp.port}" path="${sftp.path}" user="${sftp.user}"
            password="${sftp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP" />
        <logger message="#[flowVars.originalFilename] sent to sftp service"
            level="INFO" doc:name="File sent" />
    </flow>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

**EDIT**

Though Mule is built on Java, and Mule applications are built behind the scenes using Java and Spring, there is no writing of actual Java code involved in creating a Mule flow.

Comment: This might help: [DH key size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 2048 (inclusive)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40381968/3776858)

Comment: Changing the provider list should be done in your code _before_ invoking jsch. If you can't do that, you can also configure it in the file JRE/lib/security/java.security through j8 or JRE/conf/security/java.security in j9 (and I expect 10), with the caveat those apply to _all_ programs run in that JRE. PS: WinSCP works because it uses a completely different protocol implementation, namely the one in C from putty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the provider seems to be the way to go here. Unfortunately, there is no way to do so with Mule connectors, so we kind of have to re-write the sftp connector in plain Java. After downloading the bouncycastle .jars, put them in src/main/app/lib, then add them to the build path. You should be able to import them (for some reason I had to import org.python.bouncycastle.jce.provider rather than org.bouncycastle.jce.provider). At the top of my code I put :

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

and when the flow runs, the dh key is properly negotiated and no errors are thrown.