# Intellij Idea in debug mode throw java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: DH key size must be multiple of 64

Tags: java, intellij-idea, derby

I have my java project in Intellij Idea, the app in the project connect to a database (apache derby).

If I run the application **not** in debug mode I get no errors, no exceptions, it seems to work fine.

If I run the application in Intellij debug mode I get:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: DH key size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 8192 (inclusive). The specific key size 256 is not supported
```

when this happen it asks to open Intellij decompiler. This happen when I try to connect to the database.

I don't understand what is the right behaviour, if there are some problems or not.
I have to consider the one in normal run or the one in debug mode?
Same jvm version is both the tests.

Thanks for the help

UPDATE:
Just to add another thing: if after this exception caught by the debugger I resume the program execution it seems to work with no problem. It doesn't throw it again, at lest from my tests.

Comment: Which jre/jdk are you using? Do you use a different configuration for running and debugging?

Comment: I tried with different jdk versions, 11-17, AdoptOpenJDK/Temurin but still the same. I have the class with main method I run it with "Run App.main()" or "Debug App.main()" or with the run configurations that it creates but it is always the same. In debug mode I get this exception. I run it as jar outside of Intellij and no problems.

Comment: I would try adding bouncy castle to your java version, something as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381968/dh-key-size-must-be-multiple-of-64-and-can-only-range-from-512-to-2048-inclusi)

Comment: Thanks for your informations, I have already tried to add bouncy caste but I was using `Security.addProvider(...)` to register it and this didn't work. If, as in the question you linked, I use `Security.insertProviderAt(..., 1)` it works, no more Exception in debug mode. But this still doesn't explain why the exception happen only in debug mode of Intellij.

Comment: Try sharing the complete details of the exception you get, maybe there are some clues in those details.